# Error no mobile provisioning profile found

Tags: ios, xcode, google-chrome, webrtc, ninja

While using the build system instruction from `https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/` all went fine except following error

`Error: no mobile provisioning profile found for`

When i do `xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning` i do see my certificates, Is there anyway to fix it?

```
$ gn gen out/ios_64 --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64"'
Done. Made 719 targets from 110 files in 2444ms

$ ninja -C out/ios_64 AppRTCMobile
ninja: Entering directory `out/ios_64'
[2086/2100] CODE SIGNING //webrtc/sdk:r...(//build/toolchain/mac:ios_clang_arm64)
FAILED: WebRTC.framework/WebRTC WebRTC.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources WebRTC.framework/embedded.mobileprovision 
python ../../build/config/ios/codesign.py code-sign-bundle -t=iphoneos -i=3F06B010E7BE32A3D212219D02DF440B0F20D6A3 -e=../../build/config/ios/entitlements.plist -b=obj/webrtc/sdk/WebRTC WebRTC.framework
Error: no mobile provisioning profile found for "org.webrtc.WebRTC".
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Does the XCode version work?  Also, do you have multiple certs? Sometimes it just picks the first by default, if you have an expired one it might not work.

Comment: "please do follow up on this without instead of just commenting once"  Not sure what you are saying here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell the steps that works for me

1. Edit the file `src/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/ios/Info.plist` and change the value `com.google.AppRTCMobile` with your own bundle identifier.
2. Edit the file `src/sdk/objc/Framework/Info.plist` and change the value `org.webrtc.WebRTC` with your own bundle identifier

I have created bundle identifiers on Xcode and after that build is successful

Comment: This actually worked well. Thanks @faraway !!

I couldn't follow your nr 2. however... The path `src/sdk/objc/Framework` exists but the `Info.plist` file doesn't seem to be there anymore. I'm on branch *m79*

Comment: probably it's the version difference. This answer is probably for v6x or something.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks anyway. It helped me a lot.